# Facebook comment box not always loading

Tags: facebook, comments, loading

I've added a facebook comment box on my website, but its only loading around 40% of the time. The other 60% nothing happens. I've tried to do some troubleshooting and came up with that, the times its not loading the height of the box is set to 0px, but when its loading it says 160px, as its supposed to.
Here is all the code related to the commentbox.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

The following is right after the body tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '389788207743820', // App ID
  channelUrl : 'file:///C:\Users\ts10027\Documents\Mina webbplatser\recensionsida\channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
};
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=389788207743820";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and this is placed where I want my box

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.stadskoll.nu/restaurang/harrys.php" data-num-posts="2" data-width="565px" data-height="160"></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If that's the code you're actually using, there are a few things you need to change:

`channelUrl : 'file:///C:\Users\ts10027\Documents\Mina webbplatser\recensionsida\channel.html', // Channel File`

This has to be on a public URL, just move the file somewhere on the server where it can be accessed by anybody.

Next, you have to  and you're including the JS SDK two times? You might want to double check that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/